# setting two different multiple regression layers

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm now working on a small project, but I don't know how I should build the model.

So, the number of inputs is 27, outputs is 163.

I need to find weights and biases by training, and I am done with this by using 5 layers including relu and dropout.

When I see a cost graph about training loss and validation loss from a tensorboard, it looks ok.

1) However, what I also need to concern about is uniformity, which is calculated as below:

```
uniformity = (max. of y - min. of y) / (max. of y + max. of y)
```

I have a real uniformity data which are given, and when I find uniformities from y_predict value, and the difference is too big from the real uniformity value.

Is there any way to add uniformity while training, so that it not only care about finding the right weights and biases, but also close uniformity?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may incorporate a uniformity constraint into your loss function during training.

```
def my_loss(labels, predictions):
  lambda_ = 0.01
  return tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions) + \
         lambda_ * uniformity(labels) / uniformity(predictions)
```